# How to write a html code for output like text (paragraph)?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, templates, flask

**I have a result.html fie, where it only gives two outputs. But i'm trying to write a code for output with complete text like sentence or a paragraph. Below is the result.html code and image**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
        <div id="brandname">
            ML App
        </div>
        <h2>Spam Detector For SMS Messages</h2>
        
    </div>
    </header>
    <p style="color:blue;font-size:20;text-align: center;"><b>Results for Comment</b></p>
    <div class="results">


        
    {% if prediction == 1%}
    <h2 style="color:red;">Spam</h2>
    {% elif prediction == 0%}
    <h2 style="color:blue;">Not a Spam (It is a Ham)</h2>
    {% endif %}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the respective image is

[image]

But, i'm working for a text summarization problem statement, how to change the html code for that? Below is the image for text summarization

[image]

If i click on the summarize button, the output must be complete text.

**Can anyone help me with this code?**

Comment: Did you read the error message? In v3 the first argument to `add_pipe` should be the string name of a component, in this case `"ner"`. So you should have `ner = nlp.add_pipe("ner", last=True)`.

Comment: Yaa, we have either change the code or we have install spacy 2 version.